# 'dllimport' attribute only applies to variables, functions and classes warning even though applied to class function

Tags: c++, c++builder

I'm in the middle of a port to the newest c++ Builder 11 (Clang) compiler and I ran into a warning that I don't understand

The warning:

```
'dllimport' attribute only applies to variables, functions and classes
```

The simplified code:

```
class Test
{
   public:

   Test() ;

   int __declspec(dllimport) (*DllFunction)  (int a, int b) ;

} ;
```

And during construction (for instance) I load the dll and find a pointer for `DllFunction`

This **is** a function, so .. why the warning ?
What am I not getting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, `dllimport` cannot be used to import individual class methods. Only *standalone* variables and functions, and *whole* classes. However, `dllimport` is meant for **static linking** only, but you are using **dynamic loading** instead, so there is no need to use `dllimport` in this code at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can't `dllimport` a member function without `dllimport`-ing the whole class - this is where your `dllimport` should be.

Comment: You mean `__declspec(dllimport) class Test` ?  What about all the other functions in that class then (not in the example) that essentially don't interface with the dll ?  Are they going to play nice with other code ?  I can't seem to fully comprehend the impact

Comment: You must make the class public, the compiler cannot generate a member function call if it does not know about the class. You can always have private members if you want to. However there is no mechanism which allows some member functions from another class only if it is the same file (compilation unit).

Comment: I find that if I remove `__declspec(dllimport)` entirely, everything works fine.  I thought it fulfilled the same function as `__cdecl` where the latter is a calling convention.

Comment: @Peter "*I thought it fulfilled the same function as `__cdecl`*" - no, it does not. It is used for something else entirely. It has no place in the code shown, that is why the code works when you remove it.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks.  So c++ Builder 2009 simply ignored it then.